# spark-mongo connector to HDFS in csv

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark-mongo connector (in R lenguage) to query collections, when I select fields and save result as follow:

```
 t2 <- sql(sqlContext, "select name,age from members");
 saveDF(t2, "hdfs://server:8020/path/res")
```

It saves result on **parquet files with json content** but I want in a simple plain text in hdfs.

¿How can I parse this dataframe into csv format in HDFS?
  I expect:

```
   Peter,20
   Mike,15
   John,30
```

Comment: Perhaps using the https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv to write the dataframe will work?

Answer (score 1):

@Ross thanks, that was the solution:

```
  write.df(dataframe, "hdfs://server:8000/path/hdfs", "com.databricks.spark.csv", "overwrite")
```